# How to pass an array to service stack service from client side using jquery

Tags: serialization, knockout.js, servicestack

I have an Array in the javascript object. I am using jquery ajax call to process the object. Using KnockoutJS,{ko.toJSON} I  am getting the json string of the javascript object. Then using Json.parse() Passing the string to the ajax call which calls the service stack service. I am using service stack to process the object. 
I am getting nothing in testArray in the service 
Please guide me to solve this issue.  the code snippet is as follows

Why it is giving nothing in test array

```
    //View Model

    vmSaveCompanySettings = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ClientName = ko.observable("");
    self.CompanyContact = ko.observable("");
    self.testArray=["1","2"];
  };

//Ajax call
function SaveCompanySettings() {



    var jsondata = ko.toJSON(objvmSaveCompanySettings, ['ClientName', 'CompanyWebsite','testArray'])

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",

        dataType: "jsonp",

        data: JSON.parse(jsondata),
        processdata: true,


        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.ErrorMsg == "") {
                GetCompanySettings();
            }

        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
    });



 }


'Service Request method in the  service stack  

Public Class UpdateCompanySettingsRequest
    Implements IReturn(Of UpdateCompanySettingsResponse)
    Public Property ClientName As String
    Public Property CompanyWebsite As String

    Public Property testArray As List(Of String)

End Class
```

Comment: You don't have a `CompanyWebsite` property in your VM, but everything else seems to be expecting it.

Answer (score 3):

In your jQuery ajax call, for the data property, try:

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
```

This has solved issues for me in normal MVC3/4 sites when passing arrays up.